# How to go back to the old YouTube playlist editor?

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

The new YouTube editor doesn't have all the functions of the old version, the function to add all to another playlist is no longer available.

Answer (score 1):

I found that it is possible to add parameters in the Url to disable the new design.

```
&advanced_settings=1&disable_polymer=1
```

For example to edit your Watch later playlist

```
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=WL&advanced_settings=1&disable_polymer=1
```

Then you get the small button more button at the top right with "Add all to..."